# How to translate Typescript strings in a Angular 2 app?

Tags: angular, typescript

I know of two major platforms for Angular 2 i18n: [The official way](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html), and [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate). I am much more inclined to use what the official docs recommend. For me it's very clear how to translate the HTML strings. But there is one thing I didn't get yet: How do I translate the Typescript strings?

For example, I have the following component that uses the built-in i18n solution:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'hello',
    template: `
        <h1 i18n>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
        <button (click)="notify()"></button>
    `
})
export class HelloComponent {

    private name = 'John Doe';

    notify() {
        /* How do I translate this? */
        alert(`Hello ${this.name}!`);
    }
}
```

The string placed in the HTML will be translated. But how do I translate the string shown in the alert? If there is not a native way, what would be the recommended way to accomplish this?

Comment: Looking at the docs, `i18n` seems to be specifically for *component template text*.

Comment: There isn't an official way yet. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405 Upvote this so they prioritize it!

Comment: @SimonBriggs Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular team is very focused on creating a core product with some additional services that others can optionally use (`routing`, `translations`, etc). So don't discredit any community-made libraries, that's what makes Angular so useable!

That being said, I highly recommend [`ng2-translate`](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) for your needs. You can preload translations, call them synchronously or asynchronously, and use it as a `pipe` in a template or via a service in your component classes.

Comment: is this still the case or has something changed?

Comment: yes, still. You can make somework around, like doing a component with strings and get them in a service and use as constants. More info about current state here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405